# I want to customise my contact form - New Donor

Tags: contacts

I am looking to add a field initial next to Mr so that we can create a postale letter with Mr C XX

Comment: Welcome to StackExchange! Would you be able to edit your question to provide a bit more detail about what you are looking for? The more information you can provide the more likely someone will respond with a useful answer. It would be helpful to know if your form is created in CiviCRM or using a CMS form builder and if so which CMS (Drupal/WordPress/Joomla) and form builder you are using?

Comment: As I read it he is asking for eg Title, Initial, Last Name, so i would enter Mr, P, Davis. Ari, it would help if you explain if you are also collecting First Name or not. Or if you already have first name, would a solution be to just take the first character from that when you create your letter?

Comment: using Civi CRM,we are collecting First name and Last name so yes that would be a solution to take the P from Philip

Answer (score 1):

The language of the question is a bit unclear, but I think what you want is a token that takes just the first letter of the first name.  You don't need to collect it separately to do so.

If this is what you're looking for, please leave a comment to this answer saying so.  I have an extension that adds a "middle initial" token, I could quickly adapt it for your situation.

Comment: yes that is. Sorry for the vagueness